# A word similar to "fleet" that would apply to IoT technology?

Tags: synonyms, technology

If the navy deploys a fleet of vessels or a courier deploys a fleet of trucks, what would a hardware manufacturer deploy if each unit was part of a collective that connected to a cloud infrastructure?

Think of Nest thermostats as an example. Something similar to "arsenal" or "inventory" etc.., what word would describe all the thermostats that are working in people's homes that Nest could consider part of their ______ ?

Comment: Those  would be "connected IOT devices'

Comment: Doesn't that depend on the programming language?

Comment: I was hoping for an agnostic word - like say I want to make a table in the database where each of these units can be registered before they are shipped, and then they can be activated via QR code - what could I name this table other than "deployed_devices" or "registered_units". It got me thinking about fleet, but that's pretty specific to vehicles so I was curious if there's another word that's slipping my mind.

Comment: Installed base?

Comment: Something similar to "portfolio" or "registry" maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lots of people use the term "swarm", but that sometimes has a negative connotation.

[Swarm](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/swarm) (MW, noun definition 2a)

> a large number of animate or inanimate things massed together and usually in motion